# SQL using multiple values in a subquery in the same table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have one table that has multiple rows with multiple event types.

Every start event has an end event. Due to a design choice, the start event has the end event's ID in a column, but not the other way around. Similarly, the start reason is not the same as the end reason.

My columns are:

```
eventTYPE - the type of event (start, end, terminate etc)
eventID - unique ID
eventDate - date the event will happen
endEvent - ID of end event (if event type <> start - this will be NULL)
reason - Reason for the event
```

I need to return all the eventType=END that's comparitive eventType=START's reason is not of a certain reason on a user specified date.

I know I need to use the following three statements, but I am not sure how to combine them.

```
SELECT eventId 
FROM Events
WHERE eventType='END' and eventDate='<USER SPECIFIED>'

SELECT endEvent    
FROM Events
WHERE eventType='START' and reason <> 'mgp' and endEvent='<ID FROM ABOVE>'

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Events 
WHERE eventType='END' and eventId='<END EVENT FROM ABOVE>'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ....Why are you storing end events in this table?  I mean, these are for events like concerts, etc, right?  Why not just put the ending date (or the duration) in the same row?  What's the difference between an 'end' event and a 'terminate' event?  Why are the reasons for start and end events different?

Answer (score 2):

The query is something like this:

```
select *
from events se left outer join
     events ee
     on se.endevent = ee.eventid and se.eventtype = 'start' and ee.eventtype = 'end'
where ee.eventdate = '<USER SPECIFIED>' and
       se.reason <> 'mgp'
```

This just joins the events together, matching the start and end record, and then applies the logic to that result.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Events 
WHERE eventType='END' and eventId IN (

   SELECT endEvent    
   FROM Events
   WHERE eventType='START' and reason <> 'mgp' and endEvent IN (

      SELECT eventId 
      FROM Events
      WHERE eventType='END' and eventDate='<USER SPECIFIED>'

   )
)
```